# Excel IF Statement

Tags: excel-formula

In my Excel worksheet E7 = 159.99 and H7 = 0.00%

I am trying to use an IF statement to get the correct result which should be 5%.  However, if I use it in a nested IF statement like this:

```
=IF(H7>=8%,20%,IF(H7>=6%,15%,IF(H7>=3%,10%,IF(H7>0%,5%,IF(AND(H7=0%,E7>0,),5%,0)))))
```

The result is 0%.

When I break it down to just this part:  `=IF(AND(H7=0,E7>0,5%)` I get the desired result of 5%.

What is wrong with the way I originally did it for it to be producing 0% instead of 5%

Comment: Remove the `,` from: `IF(AND(H7=0%,E7>0,)` so: `IF(AND(H7=0%,E7>0)`

Comment: fwiw: `=IF(H7>0,INDEX({0.05,0.1,0.15,0.2},MATCH(H7,{0,0.03,0.06,0.08})),IF(E7>0,0.05,0))`

Answer (score 1):

In this section of your original formula, you have an extra comma in the AND function:

```
=IF(AND(H7=0%,E7>0,),5%,0)
```

The extra column is causing a third input value of nothing, which evaluates to FALSE, causing the whole AND function to return false. I.e., right now, your function is the same as:

```
IF(AND(H7=0%,E7>0,FALSE),5%,0)
```

In your broken down part, you've included 5% after the extra comma as the third argument. Any non-zero amount is treated as TRUE. So that version works because it's the same as:

```
IF(AND(H7=0%,E7>0,TRUE),5%,0)
```

You just need to remove the extra comma and third argument:

```
IF(AND(H7=0%,E7>0),5%,0)
```

So the full formula is:
    =IF(H7>=8%,20%,IF(H7>=6%,15%,IF(H7>=3%,10%,IF(H7>0%,5%,IF(AND(H7=0%,E7>0),5%,0)))))